# Checking ignore() for values

Tags: c++, stream

When you use ignore() in C++, is there a way to check those values that were ignored?  I basically am reading some # of chars and want to know if I ignored normal characters in the text, or if I got the newline character first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so - you'd have to "roll your own".

In other words, I think you'd have to write some code that read from the stream using `get()`, and then add some logic for keeping what you need and ignoring the rest (whilst checking to see what you're ignoring).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually want to ignore the characters, don't use `ignore()` to extract them. [`get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/) can do the same job but also stores the extracted characters so that you can inspect them later.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the optional `delim` parameter to `ignore()`, then it can stop at a newline:

```
streampos old = is.tellg();
is.ignore(num, '\n');
if (is.tellg() != old + num) {
    // didn't ignore "num" characters, if not eof or error then we
    // must have reached a newline character.
}
```

There's a snag, though - when `ignore()` hits the delimiter, it ignores that too. So if you hit the delimiter exactly at the end of your set of ignored characters, then `tellg()` will return `old + num`. AFAIK there's no way to tell whether or not the last character ignored was the delimiter. There's also no way to specify a delimiter that isn't a single character.

I also don't know whether and when this is likely to be any faster than just reading `num` bytes and searching it for newlines. My initial thought was, "which part of the difference between `ignore()` and `read()` is non-obvious?" ;-)